# Express.js ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, ejs, body-parser

In my main.js file the string is "hello,0,,0,0" (empty at 2nd position if u read it in array) it need to be able to pass NULL into the database.  
FYI: it will work if the 2nd position is a 0 and not empty
I am trying to split the string "," into var as shown below.

```
var Val = req.body.string.split(","); 
var one = Val[0];
var two = Val[1];
var three = Val[2];
var four = Val[3];
var five = Val[4];
let sqlquery = "INSERT INTO TESTING (one, two, three, four, five) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

let newrecord = [one, two, three, four, five];  
db.query(sqlquery, newrecord, (err, result) => {
if (err) {
return console.error(err.message);
} else
res.send("Added in database");
```

and i got this error 
ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'three' at row 1

 The table i created: CREATE TABLE TESTING (one VARCHAR(50), two BOOLEAN, three INT(4), four INT(4), five BOOLEAN ,PRIMARY KEY(name)); 
fields are all NULL
No auto increment in the table above, there is another table i created using the exact same way but with auto increment id but still throws the same error

Comment: the third value is supposed to receive an integer but it's receiving the empty value from your array Val[2] you can configure your column to receive null or if the val[2] is empty convert it to 0 before inserting

Comment: @nermineslimane it is null in my sql already and it should insert null into the database and not 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that parameter `three` is a number, you could write

```js
var three = Val[2] || null;
```

I assume you later execute a command like

```js
db.query(sqlquery, [one, two, three, four, five]);
```

Then, if `Val[2] = "0"`, you get `three = "0"`, and this string value is accepted by the database for a numeric 0.

But `Val[2] = ""` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, therefore you get `three = null`, and this is hopefully accepted by the database for a NULL value.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it throws back the same error

Comment: is it because it read null as a string rather than the real NULL?

Comment: Can you post the command where you send the `sqlquery` to the database?

Comment: CREATE TABLE TESTING (one VARCHAR(50), two BOOLEAN, three INT(4), four INT(4), five BOOLEAN ,PRIMARY KEY(name));

Comment: No, not the table creation statement, but the Javascript command that issues the SQL insertion statement.

Comment: let sqlquery = "INSERT INTO TESTING (one, two, three, four, five) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

let newrecord = [one, two, three, four, five];  

db.query(sqlquery, newrecord, (err, result) => {
if (err) {
return console.error(err.message);
} else
res.send("Added in database");

Comment: i have update the question you can take a look

Comment: Don't understand why this doesn't work, the [mysql package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) says: "undefined / null are converted to NULL".

Comment: IT WORKED!! THANKS